# How do you put text above or below a RadioButton in Android

Tags: android, position, radio-button, label, radio-group

I was trying to figure out how to fit a set of radiobuttons into the available space. The problem was that I was using a horizontal layout and the text beside each button made the whole radiogroup too big to fit. It looked ugly. What I wanted to do was to put the text for each radio button above the radiobutton.

Answer (score 1):

This answer is actually WRONG. I discovered, with some additional testing, that putting the LinearLayouts and TextFields in the RadioGroup gives you a non-functional RadioGroup. The only way I could restore proper functioning was to remove the TextFields and LinearLayouts. I had to become a little more creative in how I arranged things in order to get stuff to fit.

It just goes to show that when you think you're being clever, you usually aren't. :)

------- Wrong Answer --------

I discovered that I could put layouts within the radiogroup, so I used a vertically oriented LinearLayout for each of the radiobuttons within the radiogroup. I included a textfield above each button and put the label text in there. I removed the label text from the button itself, and voila, I had a radiogroup with the labels for the buttons above the buttons.

Here's an example:

```
 <RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/bar_display_filter_radiogroup"
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:checkedButton="@+id/bar_filter_all"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:text="@string/bar_radiobutton_all_text"
            style="@style/RadioButton"
            />
        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/bar_filter_all"
            style="@style/RadioButton"
            android:onClick="onFilterClick" 
            />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            style="@style/RadioButton"
            android:text="@string/bar_radiobutton_enroute_text" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/bar_filter_enroute"
            style="@style/RadioButton"
            android:onClick="onFilterClick" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            style="@style/RadioButton"
            android:text="@string/bar_radiobutton_delivered_text"/>
        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/bar_filter_delivered"
            style="@style/RadioButton"
            android:onClick="onFilterClick"
             />
        </LinearLayout>
    </RadioGroup>
```

I hope this proves useful for someone else encountering the same problem.